# servers running in EC2 and want only one user can access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have 2 servers running in EC2 and want only one user can access one server and other user can access the second server

Comment: Are they Linux or Windows? What do you mean by "access" -- are you referring to logging into the instance using SSH? The fact that it is running on Amazon EC2 is irrelevant... you can do it in exactly the same way that you would if they were _not_ running on EC2.

Comment: liinux.....  access are s3 and ec2 read only... which way user logged in that server

Comment: You have not clarified... What you say "access", are you referring to only allowing a single person to SSH into an instance?

Comment: ACCESS through SSH

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to connect to Amazon EC2 Linux instances via SSH:

**Option 1: Normal SSH**

When a Linux computer receives a request for an SSH connection, it compares the incoming private key with the keys listed in the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. So, if the user is logging in as `ec2-user`, it will look in `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_key`.

If the private key used to initiate the SSH session matches a public key found in the `authorized_keys` file, then the connection will be permitted.

Therefore, if you wish to control which people can connect to a particular EC2 instance:

- Ask them to generate a public/private keypair and give *you* the public half
- Insert their public keypair into the `authorized_keys` file on the appropriate computer withint he home directory of the user you want them to connect as
- Instruct them to connect to the instance using the private keypair (that they did not share)

**Option 2: Amazon EC2 Instance Connect**

[EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html) works by temporarily 'pushing' a public key to the instance. The person can then connect to the instance if they have the matching private key. The SSH connection can be established either via a normal SSH client, or via a web browser SSH client.

EC2 Instance Connect uses IAM permissions to control who is permitted to connect to an instance. Authorized users need the `ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey` permission for the appropriate instance. Here is a sample IAM policy from [Set up EC2 Instance Connect - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:instance/i-1234567890abcdef0",
            "arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:instance/i-0598c7d356eba48d7"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:osuser": "ami-username"
            }
        }
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
}
```

Therefore, you can grant appropriate permissions to each user, granting them access only to specific instances.

**Option 3: AWS Systems Manager Session Manager**

[AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) uses an "SSM Agent" installed on the EC2 instance to permit inbound connections that *act like SSH* (but are actually just the agent running commands and returning the response). The benefit of using Session Manager is that **it works on instances in private subnets** because the Agent 'calls out' to the Session Manager service, allowing connection requests to return via a stateful connection. This is a *very* powerful feature!

Permission to connect to an instance via Session Manager is granted in IAM via the `ssm:StartSession` permission. Here is a sample IAM policy from [Additional sample IAM policies for Session Manager - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started-restrict-access-examples.html):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:StartSession"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:123456789012:instance/i-1234567890EXAMPLE",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:123456789012:instance/i-abcdefghijEXAMPLE",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:123456789012:instance/i-0e9d8c7b6aEXAMPLE"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:TerminateSession",
                "ssm:ResumeSession"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:session/${aws:username}-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Therefore, you can grant appropriate permissions to each user, granting them access only to specific instances.